# Show that, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\cos(\cos x) \gt 0$.

Tags: trigonometry

> Show that, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\cos(\cos x) \gt 0$.

Do not use derivative or integral. Use only basic trigonometry.

I thought about $-1 \lt \cos x \lt 1$, but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

Yes your idea if fine, indeed recall that

$$-\pi/2 < \theta < \pi/2 \implies 0< \cos \theta< 1$$

and

$$(-1,1) \subseteq (-\pi/2 ,\pi/2) $$

Comment: I was wrong, that's very embarrassing. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Really not a problem for me, you editing are always appreciate! Bye